# strange int returned from a function

Tags: c

im facing one strange scenario when the output of my function return a ENORMOUS int (4225528), when im trying to sum simple values in a var and return that var to store in a struct.

Whats hapenning ? I tried a simple pointer func that i saw here, didnt work, heres my code, anyone has idea how to solve this ?

The function is "int cadastrarPedido(int Cad);"

Executable : https://repl.it/@thzmendes/UnwrittenHorizontalStructs

Here is where i call and the func

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cadastroPedido(int Cad);
int main(void) {
  printf("Voce selecionou a opcao 4 - Cadastrar Pedido\n");
            int Cad;
            int vlr_T=0;
            printf("\nDigite numero do cadastro: ");
            scanf("%d",&Cad);

            vlr_T = cadastroPedido(Cad);
            printf("\n Valor total : %d",&vlr_T);
  return 0;
}

int cadastroPedido(int Cad){
    int Option;
    int OpcaoPedido;
    int valor=0;
    if(Cad>0)
    {
      do
      {
        printf("\nEscolha o seu pedido: ");
        printf("\n1- Pizza de Calabresa -50 reais");
        printf("\n2- Pizza de Frango - 40 reais");
        printf("\n2- Pizza de Mussarela - 30 reais");
        printf("\n2- Coca Cola- 10 reais");
        printf("\n2- Guarana- 10 reais");
        scanf("%d", &OpcaoPedido);
        if(OpcaoPedido == 1)
        {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            valor +=50;
            scanf("%d", &Option);
        }
        else
          if(OpcaoPedido == 2)
          {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            scanf("%d", &Option);
            valor +=40;
          }
        else
          if(OpcaoPedido == 3)
          {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            scanf("%d", &Option);
            valor +=30;
          }
        else
          if(OpcaoPedido == 4)
          {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            scanf("%d", &Option);
            valor +=10;
          }
          else
          if(OpcaoPedido == 5)
          {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            scanf("%d", &Option);
            valor +=10;
          }
      }while(Option == 1);
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: *"The function is "int cadastrarPedido(int Cad);"* In the enormous amount of code that you posted there seems to be everything but a function called "cadastrarPedido".

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part. I guess most of the code you show isn't really needed to replicate the problem you have? Also please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And please don't call `main` recursively. While it's not forbidden in C (unlike in C++) it's really bad behavior. Just return from your functions and use loops.

Comment: After a little more quick checking you seem to go out of bounds of your arrays. For example in `verifica_pos` you will use `200` as index of the `log` array, while the max valid index is `199`. It's possible that such indexing (which leads to *undefined behavior*) could be the root of your problem.

Comment: My bad, just fixed the question

Comment: Lastly, your indentation and code-style is inconsistent, making it very hard to read and understand the flow of your code. It also seems that `cadastroPedido` could end without you actually returning anything, which is another case of *undefined behavior* if you try to use the returned value.

Comment: sorry guys, im new to programming, i never wrote anything in c, its for a college project

Comment: Reminder that the code snippet must be reproducible. This snippet is missing the definitions for your `log` array, which I'm assuming is a global array of structs that are missing as well.

Comment: fixed it, now there's a perfect scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slapped your code a little bit. This code snippet was enough to reproduce your "bug".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cadastroPedido(int Cad);
int main(void) {
  int valor = cadastroPedido(1);
  printf("%d",valor);
  return 0;
}

int cadastroPedido(int Cad){ 
    int Option;
    int OpcaoPedido;
    int valor;
    if(1==Cad)
    {
      do
      {
        printf("\nEscolha o seu pedido: ");
        printf("\n1- Pizza de Calabresa -50 reais");
        printf("\n2- Pizza de Frango - 40 reais");
        scanf("%d", &OpcaoPedido);
        if(OpcaoPedido == 1)
        {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            valor +=50;
            scanf("%d", &Option);
        }
        else 
          if(OpcaoPedido == 2)
          {
            printf("\nPressione 1 para continuar pedindo ou 2 para volar ao menu principal: ");
            scanf("%d", &Option);
            valor +=40;
          }
      }while(Option == 1);
    }
    return valor;
}
```

You'll see that the local variable of cadastroPedido `valor` is uninitialized when the function is called. This means that the program will pick a position in memory. Due to RAM shenanigans, that position in memory may have a random value already in it.

You can avoid this by explicitly declaring it like `int value = 0`, so you will always know the starting value of that variable and so that you aren't at the mercy of preexisting memory states.

If you don't initialize variables when you declare them in C, you're at risk of tripping into these inconsistencies, specially during `+=` operations.

Comment: i just tested your code and it really works, but when i try to use it like this it doesnt : https://repl.it/@thzmendes/UnwrittenHorizontalStructs

Comment: @ThomasMendes that does work, however when you do `printf("\n Valor total : %d",&vlr_T)` you're printing the memory position of `vlr_T` in int form. To print the int value stored in `vlr_T` you do `printf("\n Valor total : %d",vlr_T)`, without the `&` specifier.